# How to incorporate Javascript embbeded atlas based animation in HTML5 properly

Tags: javascript, html, atlas

So I used Adobe Animate to publish a vector based animation. It uses a basic .png atlas to play a 18 fps loop. It is 8 bit. Basically, I want to reference the atlas via a site source location like `https://static.wixstatic.com/media/user/RECOVER_Banner%20Flash_atlas_.png`. I have limited experience with Javascript so I don't know how to modify this code to reference the atlas from a site location properly.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>RECOVER_Banner Flash</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function (cjs, an) {
var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [
  {name:"RECOVER_Banner Flash_atlas_", frames: [[802,6020,800,600],[1604,1204,800,600],[802,6622,800,600],[1604,4816,800,600],[802,5418,800,600],[1604,5418,800,600],[0,2408,800,600],[0,7224,800,600],[802,7224,800,600],[1604,0,800,600],[802,4214,800,600],[1604,1806,800,600],[802,1806,800,600],[1604,3010,800,600],[802,1204,800,600],[1604,3612,800,600],[0,602,800,600],[0,0,800,600],[0,3010,800,600],[0,1204,800,600],[0,5418,800,600],[0,1806,800,600],[1604,602,800,600],[0,3612,800,600],[1604,2408,800,600],[1604,4214,800,600],[802,2408,800,600],[0,4214,800,600],[0,6020,800,600],[0,4816,800,600],[802,0,800,600],[802,4816,800,600],[0,6622,800,600],[802,602,800,600],[802,3010,800,600],[802,3612,800,600],[2406,7224,800,600],[3208,1204,800,600],[2406,2408,800,600],[3208,0,800,600],[2406,5418,800,600],[3208,5418,800,600],[3208,602,800,600],[2406,6020,800,600],[1604,6622,800,600],[4010,3010,800,600],[2406,3010,800,600],[2406,3612,800,600],[3208,1806,800,600],[4010,4214,800,600],[3208,4816,800,600],[3208,6020,800,600],[3208,2408,800,600],[3208,3010,800,600],[2406,4214,800,600],[4010,3612,800,600],[1604,7224,800,600],[2406,4816,800,600],[4010,0,800,600],[3208,3612,800,600],[2406,0,800,600],[2406,6622,800,600],[3208,4214,800,600],[2406,602,800,600],[3208,6622,800,600],[3208,7224,800,600],[4010,602,800,600],[2406,1204,800,600],[2406,1806,800,600],[4010,1204,800,600],[4010,1806,800,600],[4010,2408,800,600],[1604,6020,800,600]]}
];
```

Here is what I think is the atlas source that I tried changing to the https location

```js
lib.properties = {
 id: '32FF965B604FBF408600E883266E961F',
 width: 800,
 height: 600,
 fps: 24,
 color: "#FFFFFF",
 opacity: 1.00,
 manifest: [
  {src:"https://static.wixstatic.com/media/user/RECOVER_Banner%20Flash_atlas_.png", id:"RECOVER_Banner Flash_atlas_"}
 ],
 preloads: []
```

Comment: What happens when you do this? Does it just not work? No errors in the console? Loading a file cross-domain can introduce some issues. If you post more info, I might be able to help further

Comment: No errors,  just shows up with complete transparency like the atlas is not reading.  I'm using wix' s html5 code embed. I don't know if there is a console log of any sort. It gives me a green checkmark when i submit the code but it won't read or play the atlas

Comment: You should be able to pop open the developer console. If the image won't load, it should show you an error. You can also look in the network panel to see if the status of it. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/